# Transfer fungible token between accounts on different nodes

Tags: kotlin, token, corda, account

I'm so new to Corda. I want to create an asset transfer environment like bitcoin without the DVP process. I based my code to worldcupticketbooking sample project and modify DVPAccountsHostedOnDifferentNodes class. I plan just sending the token without relation to any ticket. I run the code, create accounts, and issue assets to them. But when I try to transfer token between accounts with this command

> flow start MoveTokensBetweenAccounts senderAccountName: buyer3,
> receiverAccountName: buyer1, costOfTicket: 10, currency: USD

I get the error below:

✅   Starting

```
➡️   Receiving transaction proposal for signing.
   Verifying transaction proposal.
   Signing transaction proposal.
```

✅   Done

☠   Counter-flow errored

Here is my code, since I cannot debug it I fail to find what the problem is. Can someone help me what is wrong with this?

```
    InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    class MoveTokensBetweenAccounts(private val senderAccountName:String,
    private val receiverAccountName:String,
    private val costOfTicket: Long,
    private val currency: String) : FlowLogic<String>(){
        @Suspendable
        override fun call():String {
    
            //get sender info and account
            val senderInfo = accountService.accountInfo(senderAccountName)[0].state.data
            val senderAcct = subFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(senderInfo))
    
            //get receiver info and account
            val receiverInfo = accountService.accountInfo(receiverAccountName).single().state.data
            val receiverAcct = subFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(receiverInfo))
    
            //sender will create generate a move tokens state and send this state with new holder(seller) to receiver
            val amount = Amount(costOfTicket, getInstance(currency))
    
            val receiverSession = initiateFlow(receiverInfo.host)
    
            //send uuid, buyer,seller account name to seller
            receiverSession.send(senderAccountName)
            receiverSession.send(receiverAccountName)
    
            //sender Query for token balance.
            val queryCriteria = heldTokenAmountCriteria(getInstance(currency), senderAcct).and(sumTokenCriteria())
    
            val sum = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(FungibleToken::class.java, queryCriteria).component5()
            if (sum.size == 0) throw FlowException("$senderAccountName has 0 token balance. Please ask the Bank to issue some cash.") else {
                val tokenBalance = sum[0] as Long
                if (tokenBalance < costOfTicket) throw FlowException("Available token balance of $senderAccountName is less than the cost of the ticket. Please ask the Bank to issue some cash if you wish to buy the ticket ")
            }
    
    
            //the tokens to move to new account which is the seller account
            val partyAndAmount:Pair<AbstractParty, Amount<TokenType>> = Pair(receiverAcct, amount)
    
            //let's use the DatabaseTokenSelection to get the tokens from the db
            val tokenSelection = DatabaseTokenSelection(serviceHub, MAX_RETRIES_DEFAULT,
                    RETRY_SLEEP_DEFAULT, RETRY_CAP_DEFAULT, PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT)
    
            //call generateMove which gives us 2 stateandrefs with tokens having new owner as seller.
            val inputsAndOutputs = tokenSelection
                    .generateMove(Arrays.asList(partyAndAmount), senderAcct, TokenQueryBy(), runId.uuid)
    
            //send the generated inputsAndOutputs to the seller
            subFlow(SendStateAndRefFlow(receiverSession, inputsAndOutputs.first))
            receiverSession.send(inputsAndOutputs.second)
    
            //sync following keys with seller - buyeraccounts, selleraccounts which we generated above using RequestKeyForAccount, and IMP: also share the anonymouse keys
            //created by the above token move method for the holder.
            val signers: MutableList<AbstractParty> = ArrayList()
            signers.add(senderAcct)
            signers.add(receiverAcct)
    
            val inputs = inputsAndOutputs.first
            for ((state) in inputs) {
                signers.add(state.data.holder)
            }
    
            //Sync our associated keys with the conterparties.
            subFlow(SyncKeyMappingFlow(receiverSession, signers))
    
            //this is the handler for synckeymapping called by seller. seller must also have created some keys not known to us - buyer
            subFlow(SyncKeyMappingFlowHandler(receiverSession))
    
            //recieve the data from counter session in tx formatt.
            subFlow(object : SignTransactionFlow(receiverSession) {
                @Throws(FlowException::class)
                override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
                    // Custom Logic to validate transaction.
                }
            })
    
            val stx = subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(receiverSession))
    
            return ("The ticket is sold to $receiverAccountName"+ "\ntxID: "+stx.id)
        }
    }
    
    @InitiatedBy(MoveTokensBetweenAccounts::class)
    class MoveTokensBetweenAccountsResponder(val otherSide: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
        @Suspendable
        override fun call():SignedTransaction {
            //get all the details from the seller
            //val tokenId: String = otherSide.receive(String::class.java).unwrap { it }
            val senderAccountName: String = otherSide.receive(String::class.java).unwrap { it }
            val receiverAccountName: String = otherSide.receive(String::class.java).unwrap{ it }
    
            val inputs = subFlow(ReceiveStateAndRefFlow<FungibleToken>(otherSide))
            val moneyReceived: List<FungibleToken> = otherSide.receive(List::class.java).unwrap{ it } as List<FungibleToken>
    
            //call SyncKeyMappingHandler for SyncKey Mapping called at buyers side
            subFlow(SyncKeyMappingFlowHandler(otherSide))
    
            //Get buyers and sellers account infos
            val senderAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(senderAccountName)[0].state.data
            val receiverAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(receiverAccountName)[0].state.data
    
            //Generate new keys for buyers and sellers
            val senderAccount = subFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(senderAccountInfo))
            val receiverAccount = subFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(receiverAccountInfo))
    
            //building transaction
            val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
            val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
    
            //part2 of DVP is to transfer cash - fungible token from buyer to seller and return the change to buyer
            addMoveTokens(txBuilder, inputs, moneyReceived)
    
            //add signers
            val signers: MutableList<AbstractParty> = ArrayList()
            signers.add(senderAccount)
            signers.add(receiverAccount)
    
            for ((state) in inputs) {
                signers.add(state.data.holder)
            }
    
            //sync keys with buyer, again sync for similar members
            subFlow(SyncKeyMappingFlow(otherSide, signers))
    
            //call filterMyKeys to get the my signers for seller node and pass in as a 4th parameter to CollectSignaturesFlow.
            //by doing this we tell CollectSignaturesFlow that these are the signers which have already signed the transaction
            val commandWithPartiesList: List<CommandWithParties<CommandData>> = txBuilder.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub).commands
    
            val mySigners: MutableList<PublicKey> = ArrayList()
            commandWithPartiesList.map {
                val signer = (serviceHub.keyManagementService.filterMyKeys(it.signers) as ArrayList<PublicKey>)
                if(signer.size >0){
                    mySigners.add(signer[0]) }
            }
    
            val selfSignedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, mySigners)
            val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(selfSignedTransaction, listOf(otherSide), mySigners))
    
            //call FinalityFlow for finality
            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, Arrays.asList(otherSide)))
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Why you say you cannot debug? This is something important to learn. First of all you have to look at the log file of your node which exists inside `logs` folder inside your node. Second of all you can enable remote debugging with Intellij and add break points in your code to step through the code and see attribute values to find out where the error is happening. In your case, it's saying counter-flow errored; meaning it's happening on the node where the responder flow is running.

Comment: So you need to enable remote debugging on the responding node and put break points on the responder flow. To enable remote debugging; create a remote debugging configuration in Intellij, then instead of starting your node with `java -jar corda.jar`; use what's written [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-commandline.html#enabling-remote-debugging). Once you start a node that way, click on the debug icon next to your remote configuration to attach Intellij to your node.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about remote debugging, I'm also new to this environment. Thank you so much this will strengthen my hand. I'm reading the article you mentioned. One another point in my mind, do I need the otherSide session for this operation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question; but for now, let's say you're transferring from PartyA (initiator) to PartyB (responder); you need to start PartyB with remote debugging; start the flow from PartyA; and that will kick start the responder which you'll track inside Intellij using the remote configuration that you made and stopping at break-points. Obviously, make sure that your code inside Intellij matches the code that you deployed inside the nodes, otherwise you won't be able to trace the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed use the below code to move tokens between Accounts. You do not need to call the DVP flow. A simple MoveTokensUtilitiesKt.addMoveTokens should be enough.

```
package com.t20worldcup.flows;
import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable;
import com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo;
import com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.UtilitiesKt;
import com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.RequestKeyForAccount;
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.states.FungibleToken;
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.types.TokenType;
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.TokenQueryBy;
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.database.config.DatabaseSelectionConfigKt;
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.database.selector.DatabaseTokenSelection;
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.move.MoveTokensUtilitiesKt;
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.utilities.QueryUtilitiesKt;
import kotlin.Pair;
import net.corda.core.contracts.Amount;
import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandData;
import net.corda.core.contracts.CommandWithParties;
import net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef;
import net.corda.core.flows.*;
import net.corda.core.identity.AbstractParty;
import net.corda.core.identity.AnonymousParty;
import net.corda.core.identity.Party;
import net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria;
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction;
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.*;
@StartableByRPC
@InitiatingFlow
public class MoveTokensBetweenAccounts extends FlowLogic<String> {
    private final String buyerAccountName;
    private final String sellerAccountName;
    private final String currency;
    private final Long costOfTicket;
    public MoveTokensBetweenAccounts(String buyerAccountName, String sellerAccountName, String currency, Long costOfTicket) {
        this.buyerAccountName = buyerAccountName;
        this.sellerAccountName = sellerAccountName;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.costOfTicket = costOfTicket;
    }
    @Override
    @Suspendable
    public String call() throws FlowException {
        //Get buyers and sellers account infos
        AccountInfo buyerAccountInfo = UtilitiesKt.getAccountService(this).accountInfo(buyerAccountName).get(0).getState().getData();
        AccountInfo sellerAccountInfo = UtilitiesKt.getAccountService(this).accountInfo(sellerAccountName).get(0).getState().getData();
        //Generate new keys for buyers and sellers
        //make sure to sync these keys with the counterparty by calling SyncKeyMappingFlow as below
        AnonymousParty buyerAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(buyerAccountInfo));//mappng saved locally
        AnonymousParty sellerAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(sellerAccountInfo));//mappiing requested from counterparty. does the counterparty save i dont think so
        //buyer will create generate a move tokens state and send this state with new holder(seller) to seller
        Amount<TokenType> amount = new Amount(costOfTicket, getInstance(currency));
        //Buyer Query for token balance.
        QueryCriteria queryCriteria = QueryUtilitiesKt.heldTokenAmountCriteria(this.getInstance(currency), buyerAccount).and(QueryUtilitiesKt.sumTokenCriteria());
        List<Object> sum = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(FungibleToken.class, queryCriteria).component5();
        if(sum.size() == 0)
            throw new FlowException(buyerAccountName + " has 0 token balance. Please ask the Bank to issue some cash.");
        else {
            Long tokenBalance = (Long) sum.get(0);
            if(tokenBalance < costOfTicket)
                throw new FlowException("Available token balance of " + buyerAccountName+ " is less than the cost of the ticket. Please ask the Bank to issue some cash if you wish to buy the ticket ");
        }
        //the tokens to move to new account which is the seller account
        Pair<AbstractParty, Amount<TokenType>> partyAndAmount = new Pair(sellerAccount, amount);
        //let's use the DatabaseTokenSelection to get the tokens from the db
        DatabaseTokenSelection tokenSelection = new DatabaseTokenSelection(
                getServiceHub(),
                DatabaseSelectionConfigKt.MAX_RETRIES_DEFAULT,
                DatabaseSelectionConfigKt.RETRY_SLEEP_DEFAULT,
                DatabaseSelectionConfigKt.RETRY_CAP_DEFAULT,
                DatabaseSelectionConfigKt.PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT
        );
        //call generateMove which gives us 2 stateandrefs with tokens having new owner as seller.
        Pair<List<StateAndRef<FungibleToken>>, List<FungibleToken>> inputsAndOutputs =
                tokenSelection.generateMove(Arrays.asList(partyAndAmount), buyerAccount, new TokenQueryBy(), getRunId().getUuid());
        Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
        TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
        MoveTokensUtilitiesKt.addMoveTokens(transactionBuilder, inputsAndOutputs.getFirst(), inputsAndOutputs.getSecond());
        Set<PublicKey> mySigners = new HashSet<>();
        List<CommandWithParties<CommandData>> commandWithPartiesList  = transactionBuilder.toLedgerTransaction(getServiceHub()).getCommands();
        for(CommandWithParties<CommandData> commandDataCommandWithParties : commandWithPartiesList) {
            if(((ArrayList<PublicKey>)(getServiceHub().getKeyManagementService().filterMyKeys(commandDataCommandWithParties.getSigners()))).size() > 0) {
                mySigners.add(((ArrayList<PublicKey>)getServiceHub().getKeyManagementService().filterMyKeys(commandDataCommandWithParties.getSigners())).get(0));
            }
        }
        FlowSession sellerSession = initiateFlow(sellerAccountInfo.getHost());
       //sign the transaction with the signers we got by calling filterMyKeys
        SignedTransaction selfSignedTransaction = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder, mySigners);
        //call FinalityFlow for finality
        subFlow(new FinalityFlow(selfSignedTransaction, Arrays.asList(sellerSession)));
        return null;
    }
    public TokenType getInstance(String currencyCode) {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
        return new TokenType(currency.getCurrencyCode(), 0);
    }
}
@InitiatedBy(MoveTokensBetweenAccounts.class)
class MoveTokensBetweenAccountsResponder extends FlowLogic<Void> {
    private final FlowSession otherSide;
    public MoveTokensBetweenAccountsResponder(FlowSession otherSide) {
        this.otherSide = otherSide;
    }
    @Override
    @Suspendable
    public Void call() throws FlowException {
        subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherSide));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem thanks a lot. The DVP sample is so complicated for this case and I was confused with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take look at the Token Sample at [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Tokens/fungiblehousetoken). This sample simply walks through the steps of the create, issue, and transfer.

If you do not have any dvp action in your design. I would not suggest you to look at the worldcupticketbooking sample where the dvp makes the flow super complicated.

I would actually suggest you to look at the [tic-tac-thor](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Accounts/tictacthor) sample to get familiar with the account flow logic. Then try to mimic your design from the worldcupticketbooking sample.